# Delete series of recurring events on Outlook Calendar API

Tags: outlook-restapi

I can create recurring events through Outlook Calendar's API, but I haven't yet found how to delete such events all at once. The only "solution" I've come up with so far is to fetch all instances from an event within a given time range (using [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/office/office365/api/calendar-rest-operations?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#GetEventInstances)) and make API calls to delete every one of them, one by one.

However, this is not only very time-consuming, but also makes no sense when we're talking about a recurring event that was created with the RecurrenceRange type `NoEnd` (which means it's gonna repeat forever) - what time range would I pick?

I'm sorry if it's a silly question, but I've read all questions from the `outlook-restapi` tag in here that had any relation with calendars and/or recurrence and also a few other questions from that tag (along with the API's docs/reference) and really didn't find much about how to deal with recurring events once they're created.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete the master event which will internally delete all instances. https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/calendar-rest-operations#DeleteAnEvent

Comment: Your link doesn't seem to work here (the anchor #DeleteAnEvent doesn't exist for me). Is the content you're referring to the same as this?
https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/calendar-rest-operations#delete-events
If so, it doesn't mention anything related to recurring events, but I'll give it a try and come back if it works. Thanks!

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/calendar-rest-operations#delete-events

Comment: Thanks, it worked :) I just wish the documentation was clearer. It's even confusing to know whether you're dealing with Outlook API, Office365 API, Outlook Calendar API or whatever other name there is to it...